# relation 1 a 1 error insert data

Tags: grails, grails-orm, crud, domain-model

I have a relationship 1-1 domain model it my way

```
package relation1a1

class Person {
    Home home
    String name
    String aPaterno
    String aMaterno
}

package relation1a1

class Home {

    static belongsTo = [person: Person]

    String cP
    String street
}
```

When I insert data into the person table asked me to insert data in the table first job and when I try to insert data into the home table asks me to insert data into the person table.

What I try to do is a relationship 1-1 person that removing work is eliminated.

Comment: What do you mean by table `first job` and `work` table?

Comment: Thank you for answering the problem is I can not insert data in none of any two tables

Comment: It would be helpful to show how you insert `Person` and `Home`.

Answer (score 0):

Change class domain:

```
package relation1a1

class Person {
    Home home
    String name
    String aPaterno
    String aMaterno
    static constraints = {
        home nullable: true //now you can save Person instance with home=null
    }
}
```

and than:

```
def person = new Person(name: "name", aPaterno: "qwe", aMaterno: "rty")
person.save(flush: true)

def home = new Home(cP: "asd", street: "fgh", person: person)
home.save(flush: true)

person.home = home
person.save()
```